# How to test text which popup when mouse move into button in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
 public void testSuccess() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("test arribute popup");
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    WebElement searchBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='investedList']/span/span[2]/span"));


    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(searchBtn).perform();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

}
```

when mouse move into button there is popup text display as "invested list"
how to test this using selenium

Comment: Did you try method `.Gettext();` ?

Comment: First of all you capture element locator of that text. then use getText() function to read text.

Comment: how did you try that , can you please share code? I think you need to switch to popup first.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
List<WebElement> overlaysTooltips = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='investedList']/span/span[2]/span"));

for(int i = 0; i < overlaysTooltips.size(); i++){

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  
    builder.moveToElement(overlaysTooltips.get(i)).perform();       

    //get button text after hover
    if((overlaysTooltips.get(i).getAttribute("value").equals("//ur button hover string")){
                //ur condition
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
    }
```

you can use other button attribute what is in ur html code as i dont know what kind of attribute in ur html code there.
like this:

```
overlaysTooltips.get(i).getAttribute("id")
or
overlaysTooltips.get(i).getAttribute("class")
or
overlaysTooltips.get(i).getAttribute("name")
```